# JS: Can reject be left out of promises?

Tags: javascript

With promises, is it bad practice to leave out the use of `reject`?  If I just want to return a Promise to ensure this function is run in it's entirety and not block whatever follows this function.

```
function testFunc() {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            // do stuff
            resolve(true);
     })
}

testfunc().then(() => { // additional stuff});
```

Comment: It depends on the contents of `do stuff`, can you include it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, I didn't have anything specifically.  I just created this example because I was curious about using the necessity of `reject`

Comment: You don't need to reject. Though usually if you actually need a promise, there's a case where you would want to (e.g. catching an exception).

Comment: A promise should always resolve *or* reject. A promise that never does either is indeed “a bad promise”. Following on: a reject is then (only) useful when the promise work ends in a “non-resolved” state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a chance of the `do stuff` throwing an error, then you *should* make sure to use `reject` and call it in case there's an error, so that the caller can see that there was a problem and (hopefully) handle it appropriately. For example, you wouldn't want to do:

```
function testFunc() {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            getApi((error, result) => {
                resolve(result);
            });
     });
}
```

but instead

```
function testFunc() {
     return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
            getApi((error, result) => {
                if (error) reject(error);
                resolve(result);
            });
     });
}
```

If there's really no chance of the contents of the function erroring (barring logic bugs that could be unknowingly present in any code), then `reject` won't help you, because you don't really have any place suitable to put it. For example:

```
function someWeirdPromiseFunctionThatBlocks() {
     return new Promise((resolve) => {
         for (let i = 0; i < 1e5; i++) {
         }
         resolve();
     });
}
```

Note that if you just want to:

> not block whatever follows this function.

then just returning a Promise won't accomplish that, because the Promise constructor will run all of its code *synchronously* until it encounters something asynchronous (like `getApi`). To avoid blocking the running of sync code below, use `Promise.resolve` or `setTimeout`, eg:

```
function testFunc() {
    return Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => {
            // do other stuff
        });
```

Comment: thanks!  In your last example, would that `for` loop by synchronous already and not require a Promise?

Comment: If the purpose is to `not block whatever follows this function`, then you'll need a Promise (or a `setTimeout`, or something like it) for the loop not to block what comes below the function.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not necessary at all. reject is meant to be used in a similar way as one might use `throw` - it's for errors that happen.

In fact, if you're familiar with javascript's async/await syntax, this async function...

```
async function doSomething() {
  throw new Error('Oh no!')
}
```

...roughly translates to this:

```
function doSomething() {
  return Promise.reject(new Error('Oh no!'))
}
```

which shows how reject is intended to be used wherever you might normally throw an error.

Here's an example promise that I use often where there isn't any "reject" that would make sense:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))

wait(1000).then(() => console.log('done'))
```

Many others such examples exist.

Comment: thanks @scotty.  Interesting, you use this like example like a `sleep()` method in PHP that just delays the execution of code ?

Comment: yep, that's exactly what the wait() function does